# Adding UIViewController as container on top of main VC EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to present a UIViewController in a UIView on top of the current UIViewController?  I've done swapping view controllers but when I try doing this, I get an error after presenting and removing the UIView several times and then clicking on the main VC's table.  Here's what I have when a navigation bar button is clicked:

```
- (void)composeMessage:(id)sender{
    if (_container.frame.origin.x != 350) {
         [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            [_container setFrame:CGRectMake(350, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [_CFVC removeFromParentViewController];
        }];
    }else {
        _CFVC = [[CFVC alloc]init];
        [_CFVC willMoveToParentViewController:self];
        __weak typeof(self) weakself = self;
        _CFVC.composeTo = ^(NSString *response) {
            __strong typeof(self) strongself = weakself;
            [strongself newMessage:response];
        };
        [self addChildViewController:_CFVC];
        _CFVC.view.frame = _container.bounds;
        [_container addSubview:_CFVC.view];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.05 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            [_container setFrame:self.view.bounds];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [_CFVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        }];
    }
}
```

When swapping VCs in and out, from examples I've seen, one VC has to be removed from parentViewController.  Am I supposed to remove the main VC before I add the `_container` view with the second VC, and then add it back?

UPDATE:

After removing `[_CFVC removeFromParentViewController];`, I don't get the error anymore.  Since I add a child view, shouldn't I have to remove it when it goes off the screen?  Is there anything wrong with removing `removeFromParentViewController`?

UPDATE2:

Also I moved the initialization of the second VC to the viewDidLoad method and I re-inserted removeFromParentViewController...and no errors...

Comment: There s a Container View Controller. Which embeds your View Controller in a UIView in Storyboard. Have you tried that ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d I'm doing everything programmatically and the examples I've seen uses a UIView and then adds the VC's view to the container UIView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call "[_CFVC removeFromParentViewController];" is needed and before to this you need to remove its view also which is getting added as subview to _container. Call [_CFVC.view removefromsuperview] also.
Instead of setting frame explicitly - _CFVC.view.frame = _container.bounds;
You can make it while creating _CFVC using initWithFrame:.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try following method? Instead of manually creating a UIView and adding a view controller to it, the following method does that for you

```
 presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

Comment: I'm using a UIView instead of presenting a modal one.  I'm trying to implement the "slide from the side" animation.

Comment: You can always make the model transparent and animate the viewcontroller's view.

Comment: As a custom animation, using a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I think its possible. yes